# Google+ username not getting in ios

Tags: google-plus, ios7.1

hi I want to get the User name of the google+. and I can get the user email address. this is my code to get the email and the username.

`

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error: (NSError *) error {
NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
if (error) {
    // Do some error handling here.
} else {
    NSString *serverCode = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].homeServerAuthorizationCode;
    NSLog(@"%@", signIn.authentication.userEmail);

    newuser.strSocialEmail=signIn.authentication.userEmail;



    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
    // 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

    // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
    [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

    // 3. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.*
    plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";
    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    //Handle Error
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"Email= %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
                    NSLog(@"GoogleID=%@", person.identifier);
                    NSLog(@"User Name=%@", [person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", person.name.familyName]);
                    NSLog(@"Gender=%@", person.gender);
                }
            }];






    newuser.strSocialNetworkType=@"g+";
    newuser.strFBGplusUsername=@"Name";
    newuser.strFBGplusNickname = @"Nick";
    newuser.strSocialOrNot=@"SOCIAL";
}
```

}

`

But it always exit from this point. The content of inside this is not execute

`[plusService executeQuery:query
                completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                    GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                    NSError *error)`

Why is that and how can I overcome this problem. What is the wrong I have done?
 Please tell me.
Thank you

Comment: Have you set shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail when signing in?

GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;